# Flutter Error on line 6, column 5 of pubspec.yaml: A dependency may only have one source. sdk: flutter ^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Tags: flutter

I keep getting

```
Running "flutter packages get" in flutter_sportters...
Error on line 6, column 5 of pubspec.yaml: A dependency may only have one source.
    sdk: flutter
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

When I run `my app` or `Packages Get`.

It worked perfectly fine before. Have no idea how to fix this.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thank you so much. I read that and will remain it myself!

Comment: There is probably an indentation in your `pubspec.yaml` file. Please post it so we can check.

Comment: please, post your `pubspec.yaml` in your answer

Answer (score 95):

Consider you are going to use this package "shared_preferences".

You will get this error in pubspec.yaml. If you did like below.

```
dependencies:
 flutter:
  sdk: flutter
  shared_preferences: v0.4.2
```

Indention is important you are accidentally adding shared_preference package below flutter dependency. So the error "A dependency may only have one source"

Correct format below:

```
dependencies:
 flutter:
  sdk: flutter

 shared_preferences: v0.4.2 #no indention
```

Comment: Wow.  Just had a flashback to the 80-column coding pads and IBM 029 I used the '70s.

Answer (score 43):

It throws an error because of ***Indention***. It is important to maintain Indention while adding a dependency in flutter.

***Before :***

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  english_words: ^3.1.0
```

***After :***

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
english_words: ^3.1.0
```

*Hope this will solve your error.
Happy coding!!!*

Answer (score 18):

Indentation !!!
Being newbees making silly mistakes. I have written the new dependency inside the flutter root as :

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
    sqflite:
```

Instead of

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  sqflite:
```

Comment when you see the difference!!

Comment: Seen the difference

Answer (score 10):

I was trying to add `assets` folder to my project. I added it under `dependencies` which caused the error:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
    assets:
      - images/
```

It's not to be added under `dependencies`. Instead, add it under `flutter`:

```
flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
  assets:
    - images/
```

Comment: Thank you! Even though this is mentioned in the comments in the pubspec boilerplate code, it's easy to miss from time to time and slip up.

Answer (score 5):

You can define just like that in **pubspec.yaml** file

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  image_picker: 0.4.1
```

and **flutter packages get** you can call via terminal or if you are using Android Studio than options availbale above when you edit **pubspec.yaml** file.

In **terminal** go to *your project directory* and then enter **flutter packages get**

Answer (score 4):

I solve My problem:

Here my first Code

```
dependencies
flutter:
    sdk: flutter
    webfeed: ^0.4.2

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
```

after I change it

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  webfeed: ^0.4.2

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
```

I thing you must to put your package name in the same number colunm of `flutter:` and `cupertino_icons:`

Comment: Thanks. I was making this mistake. Writing the new package inline with flutter: solved the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Check indentations as flutter package in `pubspec.yaml` takes single dependency source.

Answer (score 1):

make sure, the name of your project is not same as any package ,
this too cause for this error

Answer (score 0):

open your pubspec.yaml file

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  country_code_picker: ^1.0.4
```

Answer (score 0):

Other answers are correct. I would also like to add that I was trying to add `shared_preferences` and even though my indentation was correct, I was still getting the error mentioned in the question. To resolve it I changed the name of my project as it was also `shared preferences`

Answer (score 0):

I kept getting this error no matter what I did, including commenting out the new lines.  Finally, I put them back in with the correct indentation and ran the program.  The problem magically resolved itself.  However, the indentation is critical.

Answer (score 0):

I am getting this error due to duplication of a package in dependencies 
i.e: 
dependencies:

flutter:
    sdk: flutter

```
**cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2**
  english_words: ^3.1.5
```

# The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.

**cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2**

I solved this error by removing duplication then **Flutter clean** and then **Flutter Packages Get**.

Answer (score 0):

Its due to indentation: check out correct way

name: flutter_app
description: A new Flutter application.

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
    flutter:
      sdk: flutter
    http: "0.11.3+17"
    autocomplete_textfield: ^1.6.4

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem turns out the name of my app and the package name were same which resulted into this error.

name of the app scrapy and the dependency was also scrapy...

Changed the name and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

After checking all other solutions if the problem still persists
make sure whether the specified library is installed correctly or not. This error also encounter when the library is not installed correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Use This extension for batter experience : [YAML](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=redhat.vscode-yaml)

Example:

[image]

Happy coding‍.