# Import dart package

Tags: android, dart, visual-studio-code, flutter

I have a problem with import in the flutter and an error occurs when I change the pubspec.yaml
Or when adding something to it
This error gets

```
Error on line 18, column 5 of pubspec.yaml: A dependency may only have one source.
    sdk: flutter
```

Comment: paste your  pubspec.yaml here

Comment: name: app
description: A new Flutter project.
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
    sqflite: any
    path_provider: any
    intl: ^0.15.7
cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
flutter:
 uses-material-design: true

Comment: Packages get not working I have an error

Comment: Sounds like a problem with indentation. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49475038/flutter-error-on-line-6-column-5-of-pubspec-yaml-a-dependency-may-only-have-on

Answer (score 1):

You must set a specific version for your dependencies So check the latest version of `path_provider` and `sqflite` from this links: [path_provider](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/path_provider), [sqflite](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/sqflite) and put the version number instead of `any`.
Also consider indentation in yaml is important.

Comment: [to_do_app] flutter packages get
Running "flutter packages get" in to_do_app...                  
Error on line 16, column 1 of pubspec.yaml: Only expected one document.
dependencies:
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^