# Unable to load asset:

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

Here is the error massage:

> Unable to load asset: assets/images/waiting.png
> When the exception was thrown, this was the stack Image provider:
> AssetImage(bundle: null, name: "assets/images/waiting.png") Image key:
> AssetBundleImageKey(bundle: PlatformAssetBundle#e3e67(), name:
> "assets/images/waiting.png", scale: 1.0)

here is my pubspec.yaml

```
flutter:
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  assets:
    - assets/images/waiting.png
```

Comment: Share your folder structure.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of your folder structure ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter Error on line 6, column 5 of pubspec.yaml: A dependency may only have one source. sdk: flutter ^^^^^^^^^^^^^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49475038/flutter-error-on-line-6-column-5-of-pubspec-yaml-a-dependency-may-only-have-on)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the assets folder is at the level of the lib folder of the project, and start the app again, that is, if you add an image, do not use hot reload, Restart the app the first time you add the image.

[image]