# how do I solve this dependency packages error?

Tags: android, flutter

[image]

```
Error on line 31, column 5 of pubspec.yaml: A dependency may only have one source.
   ╷
31 │ ┌     sdk: flutter
32 │ │     firebase_core: "0.4.4"
33 │ │     firebase_analytics: "5.0.11"
34 │ │     firebase_auth: "0.15.4"
35 │ │     firebase_storage: "3.1.1"
36 │ │     cloud_firestore: "0.13.2+1"
37 │ │     provider: "4.0.4"
38 │ │     image_picker: "0.6.3+4"
39 │ │     timeago: "2.0.26"
40 │ │     flutter_spinkit: "4.1.2"
41 │ │ 
42 │ │ 
43 │ │   # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
44 │ │   # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
45 │ │   cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
   │ └──^
   ╵
Running "flutter pub get" in letstalk...
pub get failed (65;    ╵)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter Error on line 6, column 5 of pubspec.yaml: A dependency may only have one source. sdk: flutter ^^^^^^^^^^^^^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49475038/flutter-error-on-line-6-column-5-of-pubspec-yaml-a-dependency-may-only-have-on)

Comment: According to the dup, delete two spaces from the start of lines 32 to 40.

Answer (score 2):

You should add the dependencies with two space back to left after the sdk: flutter

Like this

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.3
  firebase_core: ^1.0.2
  firebase_auth: ^1.0.2
```